# gTalk status icon on the notification bar

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cyanogenmod, notifications, notification-bar, google-talk

Instant Messenger apps such as Skype or Windows Live Messenger will display an icon on the notification bar with indication on the connection status. (I know gtalk is supposed to be always on after my first login, but there have been many occasions where it is not true. )

There is no status icon for Google Talk, in order to know my connection status I have to open the gtalk app and check it. Is there any way to have an icon always on the notification bar, other than using a third-party app? There are many useful features on the native client and I don't want to try various new apps.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have blue bars for your wireless and/or wifi connections and have logged into GTalk you should always be connected.

You have to sign out of GTalk or lose connection with the Google Servers (gray signal bars) in order to be offline.

Short story: as long as you signed in and have a data connection you are online for GTalk.

If that doesn't give you a warm fuzzy feeling then use a third party app like [Trillian](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ceruleanstudios.trillian.android&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd) and use it for GTalk. Trillian might be able give you a notification icon.

Comment: "you should always be connected": *should* is the key here. Many times I *should*, but I'm not. Therefore, I need some indicator. I don't want to try a new app, I'd have to compare features such as voice messages, history retention, UI, etc etc and I am fine with gtalk currently (except for its lack of status icon).

Comment: Are you running a task manager or battery extender? These may be the cause of lost connection. Have you noticed lost connection with blue bars?

Comment: I live in a place where connectivity *sucks*. Often when I get connection again (bars become blue after being grey), gtalk won't get reconnected unless I acively reopen it. A status indicator would come in handy in this situation.

Comment: Good look finding a solution.